PhonePe integration for recurring payment
I'm trying to integrate phone pe's recurring payment / subscription.

Using this Document

For the Mandate Set Up Flow

Subscription is created successfully. Steps #1 and #2
Submit AUTH Request is also executed successfully.

But how we can redirect the user to url which I got in Submit AUTH


ppesim://mandate?pa=PGTESTPAYUAT86@ybl&pn=SUBSCRIBEMID&am=100&mam=100&tr=TX667fc8fb61164&utm_campaign=SUBSCRIBE_AUTH&utm_medium=PGTESTPAYUAT86&utm_source=TX667fc8fb61164
return redirect()->to ($redirectUrl);

By using the above code I am unable to redirect the user, is there any solution?

You will get two types of redirect URL based on your request in PhonePe for recurring payments.
You will either get a Web Intent or an Android Intent. The one you posted seems like an android one since it starts with ppesim which stands for PhonePe Simulator.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This is an internal deepLink for launching the phone pay .
this will work on phone pay simulator APK , which can be downloaded from its SDK documentation .
the original deepLink differs from this . this is only for testing purpose
Download here :- https://docs.phonepe.com/public/mbz9k4cBc_SpDb09RE2j
